# JavaScript downloader

Tags: javascript, download

I want to allow a web site users to be able to download files from my site, but with the help of a client-side downloader with an ability to continue an interrupted download.

For example, I want to sent a person a file with a size of 30+ Meg. I want the user to have the best downloading experience, so I can't afford him downloading 25 Meg and then getting the download dropped due to the network problems on his side.

Therefore, I want to have a javascript downloader rendered on a download page, that will show the actual client-side file delivery, and when it is downloaded, to give an ability to a user to save the file.

Or is it not possible due to the fact that javascript won't be able to open a save file dialog and save to a file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible with JavaScript and that's why:

To continue downloading from the certain point you should send to the server the position number to start downloading from. And as JavaScript has no access to local file system, you can't get that position.

**UPD**: it seems that I was too hurrying with the reply.
The file size can be gotten using the HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) and after getting the file size you can pass it to the server which should support the partial downloading.

But anyway, after downloading another part of the file you should sew two pieces together in some way; standard web browser dialog will only suggest to overwrite the file.

**UPD2**: to work with files in some Internet Explorers you can use FileSystemObject:

```
var fso;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

Comment: You could use a cookie storing the amount downloaded and cobble it together with an AJAX downloader. But I'm not too sure..

Comment: I've updated my reply with more data, but it seems that full-featured partial downloading is not possible anyway.

Comment: @Manishearth, as I see, when the connection breaks, PHP can't track that and can't send the proper cookie headers after connection is lost.

Comment: Basically you don't use PHP, you use AJAX to get the file. And periodically update the cookie.

Comment: Okay, but to do that you anyway should have access to a file. And if you have that access you don't need periodical cookie updates as you can get actual file size at any time :)

Comment: Oops.. How about making a PHP script that sends the file chunk-by-chunk. As in `fetchfile.php?file=abc.pdf&chunk=52&chunksize=1kb`. Now you can ajax-fetch these chunks and assemble them. Of course, we still have the issue of taping together an inturrupted download. =P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8789/discussion-between-minras-and-manishearth)

Comment: Guys, my idea was to never be saving file to a disk until it is completely downloaded. The contents of a file would be cached into a javascript memory and only when ready - get flushed to a drive via standard HTML save file dialog. Would that be possible? For example if I am sure that my files are never larger then 200 MB and I am ready to have the user suffer his browser memory usage increase by that size.

Comment: Well, you can download your files/chunks to disk and read them (with HTML5). Then you can assemble the pieces together in memory. But you can't later save the files from memory to disk using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into making a plugin or extension. Like those DownloadThemAll extensions for firefox and Google chrome. Another alternative would be to use Flash, either alone or integrating it with javascript like hinted here: http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=0922A